# Google Sheets: Lookup Value that falls after a Timestamp

Tags: google-sheets

Need serious assistance. Please see images below for a reference.

I have 2 sheets - The second image represents a sheet that is connected to a Google Form. This inputs the site information for various machines. Machines can move between sites on different weeks.

The first image represents a sheet that aggregates various data inputs for daily fuel consumption. The intention here is to have the Site column represent where the machine would have been Located on the date that the timestamp of fuel consumption on this sheet is recorded.

I want to lookup the site location that a machine would have been at if the timestamp that the fuel is recorded falls after a date that the machine location changed. the challenge here is maintaining historic locations as the sites move around with Google Form entries.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: This was posted 5 days ago at the time of my comment, @user261687, and you have neither replied to marikamitsos nor shared a test sheet. This leads me to believe the urgency of your request was overstated. If you no longer need help, please help declutter the site by deleting the post or posting any solution you found and marking your own answer as "Best Answer."